# UILabel word wrap and slashes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a multiple lines UILabel. The text contains slash ("/") character. Usually slash is a not breaking character. But UILabel handles it as a breaking one. How to make it non-breakable?

**Example**

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
textLabel.text = @"Some text with/slash";
```

This code is rendered as:

```
Some text with/
slash
```

Should be rendered as:

```
Some text
with/slash
```

Comment: Try backslash-encoding it?

Comment: what is the width of UILabel? can you try reducing it and see.

Comment: UILineBreakModeWordWrap has been deprecated. From iOS6 should use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Slash, use this:

```
textLabel.text = @"Some text with\/slash";
```

For avoiding word wrap in label, use this;

```
[textLabel sizeToFit];
```

**Update:**
Below comment suggests that I misunderstood the problem here..

Anyhow, if you want to print it in two lines, use next line carriage ..(/r)

```
textLabel.text =@"Some text \r with/slash";
```

Working as you wanted.. :)

Let me know if any info needed.. :)

Comment: I think, You didn't understand his concept. Don't modify text. If there is other than \ in that place, it's working as he want. But word wrapping doesn't workout with part of /, that is problem here.

Comment: No No. It's not correct answer. If You've more than 1000  character in that string, how do you put that \r in your text?

Comment: @iMani .. What do you mean by " how do you put that \r in your text? " ?

Comment: Hey man, actual text in label is `Some text with/slash`. You suggest put \r before that. Then my question is if the paragraph is too long and having more words like that means, how do you put \r in that pragraph? Actually that is your answer doesn't work